# Cleanest way to implement Jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am going to be using many dialogs throughout my app, but what is the best way to implement it?

I have two ideas:

Have the dialog div on the page at the bottom of the body, but have its initial display set to none.

OR

When the trigger for the dialog to appear happens, have it appended to the body, then opened.

What do you think the pros and cons are of both methods? And if you have a better way please share!

---

Yes, I'm talking about Jquery UI:

```
$('#myDialog').dialog({
    ...
})
```

I know about the hiding and unhiding, but what is the best way to use the div it is applied to? Have it hidden to start with, or dynamically append the div to 'body', then call dialog on it?

---

@Lee Taylor - It will be a bit of both, because inside the dialogs there will be input and select fields. The select fields will be populated by an AJAX call.

---

Is having the content of the dialog filled by an AJAX call or by PHP better?

Could you also give me an example use of .clone()?

---

Thanks, what about this:

```
function manageContactDialog()
{
var content = $.load('manage-customer-contact.html') ;

$('body').append('<div id="manageCustomerDialog">'+content+'</div>') ;

$('#manageCustomerDialog').dialog({
    title: ''
})
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about using jquery-ui .dialog?  If you use that, it takes care of hiding the dialog div for you until you call .dialog('open') on it.

Comment: Depends on whether the content in the DIV(s) are particularly dynamic or whether they can be hard coded.

Comment: OK, you might be better to use a hybrid solution then. Create DIVs with static HTML. clone() them when you come to need them, then add the dynamic content just before you display the dialog.

Comment: var $DIVcopy = $('#divtemplate').clone();